# Get Operation by Name in Google Speech to Text, with nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech

I'm using Google Speech to Text Node.js client. 
When starting long-running speech transcription, I need to split the operation in two steps.
1. Start the transcription, and return the "name".
2. Ask for the status of the operation.
Ie replicating https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/async-recognize#speech-async-recognize-gcs-protocol in nodejs.

My problem is to figure out how to create an OperationsClient, and to make the getOperation({name}) to actually return the result of the transcription.

I do run this code inside two firebase cloud functions:
1. The one that starts the trancscription, and then return the "name". This one works really well with the SpeechClient.
2. Another one that should call operationsClient.getOperation aka the same as curl to "https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/operations/"

```
import gax, {GrpcClient, GrpcClientOptions, lro} from "google-gax";
const gaxOpts = {
    clientConfig: {}
}
const gaxGrpc = new GrpcClient(gaxOpts);

...

app.get('/operations/:googleSpeechRef', async (req, res) => {
    const googleSpeechRef = req.params.googleSpeechRef;

    const operationsClient = lro({
        auth: gaxGrpc.auth,
        grpc: gaxGrpc.grpc,
    }).operationsClient(gaxOpts);
try {
        const [responses] = await operationsClient.getOperation({name: googleSpeechRef},{});
        if (responses) {
            const operation = responses[0]

            console.log("getOperation. responses: ", responses)
            const initialApiResponse = responses[1]
            operation
                .on("complete", (longRunningRecognizeResponse /*, longRunningRecognizeMetadata, finalApiResponse*/) => {
                    // Adding a listener for the "complete" event starts polling for the
                    // completion of the operation.

                    const speechRecognitionResults = longRunningRecognizeResponse.results as ISpeechRecognitionResult[]
                    // resolve(speechRecognitionResults)
                    console.log("complete: ", speechRecognitionResults)
                })
                .on("progress", async (longRunningRecognizeMetadata /*, apiResponse*/) => {
                    // Adding a listener for the "progress" event causes the callback to be
                    // called on any change in metadata when the operation is polled.

                    const percent = longRunningRecognizeMetadata.progressPercent

                    console.log("progress. Percent", longRunningRecognizeMetadata.progressPercent /*, apiResponse*/)
                })
                .on("error", (error: Error) => {
                    // Adding a listener for the "error" event handles any errors found during polling.
                    // reject(error)
                    console.log("error: ", error)
                })
            res.contentType("application/json").status(200).send(JSON.stringify(initialApiResponse))
        } else {
            res.send(404)
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Failed to fetch operation by googleSpeechRef: ", googleSpeechRef, ". Error: ", error);
        res.status(500).send(serializeError(error))
    }
}
```

The error i get is:

```
{
"code": 13,
"details": "Not enough responses received",
"metadata":{
"internalRepr":{}
},
"note": "Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient",
"name": "Error",
"message": "Not enough responses received",
"stack": "Error: Not enough responses received\n at Http2CallStream.call.on (/srv/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:102:45)\n at emitOne (events.js:121:20)\n at Http2CallStream.emit (events.js:211:7)\n at Http2CallStream.endCall (/srv/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:74:18)\n at /srv/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:355:18\n at <anonymous>\n at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)"
}
```

Comment: For anybody finding this question later. My challenge was solved by this answer https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-speech/issues/10#issuecomment-415900469 ```const { google } = require('googleapis');

(async () => {
  const auth = await google.auth.getClient({
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']
  });
  const { data } = await google.speech('v1').operations.get({ auth, name: OPERATION_NAME });

  console.log(data);
})();```

Answer (score 1):

For anybody finding this question later. My challenge was solved by this answer https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-speech/issues/10#issuecomment-415900469

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');

(async () => {
  const auth = await google.auth.getClient({
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']
  });
  const { data } = await google.speech('v1').operations.get({ auth, name: OPERATION_NAME });

  console.log(data);
})();
```